Can I use only CSS operations (like calc()) to modify inline style definitions?
I use a program called Joplin that displays a small popup when you click inside of a table cell. The positioning of the popup is created on the fly and set as an inline style by the application. Example:
<div class="tox-pop tox-pop--bottom" style="position: absolute; left: 1146.71px; bottom: 617.25px; max-height: 183px; max-width: 796px;" data-alloy-placement="north">
I want to create a CSS only rule (I can't use JavaScript) that will add/subtract from the inline style's bottom: value.
I can't set a static style, because the bottom: value changes depending on where you click in the application.
Can this even be done? Maybe using calc(), or some other CSS arithmetic?
Any help appreciated.

No, you can't use calc like that. But you could add a transform: translate(...).

You can influence the value of bottom either by applying transform or margin:


body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

.tox-pop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* or */
  /* transform: translateY(-20px); */
  /* or */
  /* translate: 0 -20px; */
}
<div class="tox-pop tox-pop--bottom" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; bottom: 20px; max-height: 183px; max-width: 796px;" data-alloy-placement="north">



